# Custom attribute not getting called

Tags: c#, attributes

Okay, I'm obviously missing something, as this should be pretty simple.  I've created the following attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class EntitleAttribute : Attribute
{

    public EntitleAttribute(string permissionName)
    {
        bool hasPermission = ...
        if (!hasPermission)
        {
            throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden");
        }
    }

}
```

I put it on a method:

```
[Entitle("Access Application")]
public ActionResult MyMethod(...) { ... }
```

However, it never gets called.  What am I missing?

Comment: Attributes don't do anything by themselves - so without code that would look for the attribute it is hard to reason why noone looks for/instantiates the attribute. Looking at code maybe you think about deriving from MVC's `FilterAttribute`?

Comment: Right on.  Make this an answer and I'll mark it.  Thanks!

Comment: Another option would be to look into [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) and the commonly used [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/documentation) for an implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attributes don't do anything by themselves. There needs to be some code that would look for the attribute and do something with it.

Based on code sample you want to perform some per-authentication in ASP.Net MVC application. In this case you should derive your attribute from MVC's [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). If you need more general handling in MVC site - base [FilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterattribute%28v=VS.98%29.aspx) or even IMvcFilter provide more options.

Comment: Because I'm trying to avoid naming specific roles in the code, using ActionFilterAttribute was exactly what I needed.